# Drop Down CSS Menu?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I recently installed a drop down menu on my main menu bar and noticed something. The H1 header directly below it moves on the page when I activate the drop down menu. It's like the drop down menu pushes the text out of the way because it is in the way. The header or text moves back when the drop down menu is released. This also happens on other pages with text below. What is causing this and how can I correct it?

Comment: Are you absolutely positioning your elements and using a z-order?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say with 100% certainty without seeing your markup, but I'd guess the nested list (ul) in your menu doesn't have it's position set to absolute. Setting it to absolute takes it out of the flow of the page so it appears above other content rather than forcing any content below it down. Show your markup and I can say for certain.

Comment: Ok you are probably right. I am not a css expert yes so bear with me. I created an ul inside of a ul to create the drop down, then styled it with the following css styles. everything works fine except it forces content down below it like you say. Which of these following styles do I set the absolute position to.                                                                 1. #main-nav li ul

Comment: 1. #main-nav li ul    - paddings and margins set to 0, layout display - none.   2. #main-nav li:hover ul    - width-159, layout - display - block    3. #main-nav li li    - display-list-item, list style type - none.

Comment: #main-nav li needs position:relative and #main-nav li ul needs position: absolute.